# Never seen before C method of initialization of an array of structs found in the Linux kernel source

Tags: c, linux, arrays, struct

```
55 typedef struct pidmap {
56         atomic_t nr_free;
57         void *page;
58 } pidmap_t;
59 
60 static pidmap_t pidmap_array[PIDMAP_ENTRIES] =
61          { [ 0 ... PIDMAP_ENTRIES-1 ] = { ATOMIC_INIT(BITS_PER_PAGE), NULL } };
```

The code snippet above shows the initialization of an array of a structs that I found in the Linux kernel source. I have never seen this form of initialization before and I couldn't simulate the same thing on my own. What am I missing actually?

[Source of the code](http://www.cs.fsu.edu/~baker/devices/lxr/http/source/linux/kernel/pid.c?v=2.6.11.8#L60)

Comment: Why a c++ tag? The linux kernel does not use c++.

Comment: Should be an extension feature.

Comment: The Linux kernel uses lot of GCC specific extensions. See e.g. http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.6.3/gcc/index.html#toc_C-Extensions

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is a GNU/GCC extension called *Designated Initializers*. You can find more information about it in the [GCC documentation](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Designated-Inits.html).

> To initialize a range of elements to the same value, write `[first ... last] = value`. This is a GNU extension

Comment: Just for accuracy, designated initializers aren't a GCC extension ([see this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9849719/what-do-square-brackets-mean-in-array-initialization-in-c)), but the range syntax is.

Answer (score 5):

It is done by using a **[Designated Initializer](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Designated-Inits.html)**.

It is a gcc extension and not standard c construct. Using it results in non portable code, So avoid using such compiler extensions unless portability is least of your concerns.